# PayPal - You are not signed up to accept payment for digitally delivered goods

Tags: api, paypal-adaptive-payments, express-checkout, paypal

I just went from sandbox to live with my PayPal Express Checkout.

But when I try to use it, I get the following error:

```
You are not signed up to accept payment for digitally delivered goods.
```

My account is a business account and I have added express checkout as a payment option.

What other steps do I need to take, to get this function to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answering my own question, which hopefully can help someone in the future:

I don't know what the exact problem was - the Express Checkout (Digital Goods) didn't show at my account, only the Express Checkout option was present.

I had to write PayPal, and they enabled it manually for me..

So if you're experiencing same issues, simply just write or call PayPal, and they will help you enable it.

Comment: I have the same problem. So what do you mean by "I had to write PayPal"? Where did you write it?

Comment: @RaheelHasan To their customer support? You can also just give them a call.

Answer (score 4):

Owner of account should call to PayPal to activate option to receive payments for Digital Goods.

"Enabling your PayPal Account for Digital Goods

Please contact your sales representative to enable your account for PayPal Digital Goods. Additionally, merchants in the US or Canada can contact either 1-855-477-5673 or 1-888-818-3922 to activate Digital Goods for their accounts."

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/digital-goods/IntroducingExpressCheckoutDG/

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you need to activate the digital good functionality in your business account
- this page might be useful 
[Digital Goods for Express Checkout](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/About-Business-Archive/I-can-t-add-PayPal-for-Digital-Goods-Express-Checkout/td-p/714649)